# How to async copy files at the best speed in C#

Tags: c#, performance, asynchronous

I'm using this method for asynchronously file copy with notifications and cancellation. It is good for copy files locally. But in case of cross drive copy its performance reduces, because at every moment only one drive works. The worst situation occurs when I copy large files from SSD to slow flash or vice versa.

Can any body advice me better solution? Maybe something based on producer-consumer pattern or there are some libraries? (I have searched, but without result)

P.S.: It is not method for direct use - it is wrapped in some others, which prepares files list and choose bufferSize

```
private static async Task<long> CopyFileAsync(
    [NotNull]string sourcePath,
    [NotNull]string destPath,
    [NotNull]IProgress<FileCopyProgress> progress, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    long bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10
    )
{
    if (bufferSize <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(bufferSize));
    }

    long totalRead = 0;
    long fileSize;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    using (var reader = File.Open(sourcePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        fileSize = reader.Length;
        using (var writer = File.Create(destPath, Convert.ToInt32(bufferSize), FileOptions.Asynchronous))
        {
            while (totalRead < fileSize)
            {
                var readCount = await reader.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bufferSize), cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                await writer.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readCount, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                totalRead += readCount;

                progress.Report(new FileCopyProgress(totalRead, fileSize, null));
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
        }
    }
    progress.Report(new FileCopyProgress(fileSize, fileSize, null));
    return fileSize;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `File.Copy`? Copying won't go faster if you load the data into your program's memory first. Asynchronous operations mean that you don't have to wait for the operation to complete, not that it will run faster. You *can't* get better performance than what your disks can deliver

Comment: BTW when you copy from one dirve to another *both* drives work, unless the file is so small that the OS just buffers the entire file in in memory. How big are the files? If they are small, you could copy many of them in parallel

Comment: 1) It can be more then one copy session at the same time 2) I need to see the progress, because typical amount of data is about 10-100Gb at once 3) As I understand in current situation when drive A reads, drive B can't write and vice versa

Comment: In typical chunk there about 1000 files, most of them less then 1 Mb, but from 1 to 10 files are big - from 1-50 GB

Comment: why do you think that? When you copy a file from Windows Explorer you *do* see both drives working. 1MB by the way is small enough to fit into the processor's cache. It's definitely small enough that it can be buffered in memory before it's copied. *That* can give the appearance that only one drive is working

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you mean than File.Copy is wrapper to WinAPI function? It sounds better) but in any case I need to notify UI about progress